# clojure require works with parenthesis

Tags: clojure, namespaces, require

I was just playing around with Clojure (Version 1.1.0) and found this behavior quite odd:

```
user=> (in-ns 'greet)
#<Namespace greet>
greet=> (clojure.core/require 'clojure.core)
nil
greet=> (clojure.core/require 'clojure.string)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not locate clojure/string__init.class or clojure/string.clj on classpath:  (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
greet=> (clojure.core/require '(clojure.string))
nil
```

When I use the `require` function, it works with `'clojure.core`, but doesn't work with `'clojure.string` and works with `'(clojure.string)`. Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a years old version of clojure (which AFAIK doesn't even have `clojure.string` included). Your example code works perfectly fine in current clojure 1.5.1

Comment: And the reason `(require '(clojure.string))` works even though `clojure.string` doesn't exist is that it's parsed as a prefix list. "Require the following namespaces after prepending each with `clojure.string`: none".